# android:elevation doesn't work in L preview

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-elevation

I've been playing with the L preview for a few days, and one thing that doesn't seem to work is the `android:elevation` attribute for a view. It works just fine when calling `View.setElevation()`, but it just seems to ignore the XML attribute. I'm using Android Studio 0.8.2 and have `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` set to `'L'`, and `compileSdkVersion` set to `'android-L'`. `buildToolsVersion` is `"20.0.0"`. Here is a sample layout that doesn't work properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:elevation="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="top"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:elevation="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bottom"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of the result: imgur.com/mqeq9vK

According to the `android:elevation` I set, the bottom card should be flat on the "ground", but it isn't. In fact, it looks no different than the top card who's elevation is `5dp`. Is this a known issue, and does it work for you?

EDIT: It seems this is only the case with `CardView`, or at least it isn't an issue with `Buttons`. In this layout I replaced `CardView` with `Button`, and even though the shadow is kind of screwed up (known bug), you can still see the difference in elevation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="1dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT 2: It's pretty much confirmed that this issue only affects `CardView`, `android:elevation` works fine for any other view. For a detailed explanation of why this happens look at the accepted answer. In the meantime, my workaround is to replace the `CardView` with a `FrameLayout` and set `android:background` to a drawable. Here is an example of a card background drawable that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
```

I've also filed this as a bug, so please star this issue if it affects you. https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=731

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CardView sets its own elevation during initialization, which will override whatever you set from XML. You should file this as a bug at https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3

```
@Override
public void initialize(CardViewDelegate cardView, Context context, int backgroundColor,
        float radius) {
    cardView.setBackgroundDrawable(new RoundRectDrawable(backgroundColor, radius));
    View view = (View) cardView;
    view.setClipToOutline(true);
    view.setElevation(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cardview_elevation));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this confirms what I suspected. I'll file that bug and in the mean time I'll work out a different method then.

Comment: @alanv Do you know if this is still a bug now that Lollipop is officially out?  I still can't get it to work in XML.

Comment: You should use the cardElevation property (as mentioned in another answer from yigit, who is the developer for CardView).

Answer (score 3):

Please use [cardElevation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardElevation) property to set elevation on the CardView. This will effect shadow size pre-L as well.

Also, see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) for other attributes.

Comment: Seems like this was added after the official SDK released. Nonetheless, thanks for letting me know about this attribute! The ability to easily control shadow size on pre-lollipop is a definite benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Please add this in your root

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

below is the code for a cardview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/view" >
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    Child
    .
    .
    .
    .

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Until the [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=731) fix is released you can programmatically set it.

I've done it in a `RecyclerView` like this:

In your RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TripsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    /* ... */

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView card;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            card = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        }
    }

    /* ... */

    @Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        /// ...

        // Update Card Elevation
        final float scale = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        holder.card.setElevation(1f * scale);    //TODO set this in xml once CardView elevation bug is fixed
    }

}
```

Comment: Not working also setElevation method is only available in android 5 so the OS version check is also needed to be added.